# Как залить файл с HDD в GitHub репозиторий?

Tags: git

Задача такая есть файл index.php его нужно залить на github в созданный ранее репозиторий myaccount/index.git, какая должна быть последовательность команд?

Answer (score 11):

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:myaccount/index.git
git add index.php
git commit -am "initial commit"
git push origin master
```

А вообще вам надо почитать «[Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ru)».

Comment: на последней команде вылетает: 

Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

раньше помогала ssh-add, но в этом случае почему-то нет

Comment: Мне за вас "разжевать и проглотить"? Нужно ssh ключ добавить на ваш Github аакаунт.

Я там ссылочку внизу добавил, вот пройдите по ней, почитайте пару первых глав хотя бы.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку)